# A TV mini series (I think) people live in a fake town at the end it turns out they are in a mental institution

Tags: story-identification

We started watching Wayward Pines last night and it reminded me of a show (or mini-series) that was on years ago. It was about a fake town that people lived in. (In the end they were all mental patients living in a false reality together), There was something about holes appearing in the ground. 
I think there was a corporation involved and some people went back and forth between the real world
Does anyone remember the show?

Answer (score 13):

This is *[The Prisoner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner_(2009_miniseries))*, a 2009 remake of the classic 1960s show of the same name.

> 6 encounters new arrivals, which contradicts claims that no world
> exists. 2 shows off new houses, indicating the village is expanding.
> This is later revealed to be to increase pressure on 6 to replace 2 to
> stop the holes from destroying the village. 6 confronts 2 about the
> newcomers, but soon forgets as 2 reveals he has afflicted 6 with a
> disease that will kill him. 6 confronts 11–12 when he meets him at
> 909's grave and again at the Go Inside bar. 11–12 is unable to
> reconcile himself to his false identity. He proceeds to smother his
> dreaming mother and hang himself.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Prisoner: Checkmate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sUGnTNphko)</sup></sub>

Comment: Or, indeed, the actual 1960s show itself :-)

Comment: They ***remade*** The Prinsoner??!!   Ye Gads, Is ***nothing*** cacred?

Comment: @filth - Did the original have holes appearing?

Comment: @Mawg No they did not.  Some pranksters just put together an elaborate hoax to that effect.  The hoax included filming an entire awful miniseries under that title, "The Prisoner", and characters like "Number 6" and "Number 2."  They really went to a lot of work to pull it off.  Some people are still fooled to this day, but no, it was all just an elaborate ruse.

Comment: I know that it is against all etiquette to say "thank you" on S.E, but thank you, thank you,  ***thank you***,  for the relief which your comment provided. If only I could upvote it ten thousand times.  I felt worse there than Lister of Red Dwarf did when he heard that they had remade Casablanca

Comment: You were correct Valorum, I did figure out the show I was thinking of, It was a 2009 mini series called "The Prisoner" with Ian McKellen and James Caviezel